# Unix Timestamp -> Human readable error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, epoch

I have followed guides, read many answers on this very website, but I cannot get a unix epoch time to render properly.

This is an example timestamp as taken from the JSON file output.json

"timestamp": "1365427203000",

Here is my code

```
$.getJSON('output.json', function (data) {

    var myDate = new Date( data.RTPPMDataMsgV1.timestamp *1000);

    var timestamp_information = '<p>';
    timestamp_information += 'Last update : ' + myDate.toGMTString();
    timestamp_information += '</p>';
    // load the content into timestamp_placeholder div
    $("#timestamp_placeholder").html(timestamp_information);
```

Here is the output..

Last update : Tue, 31 Aug 45238 14:10:00 GMT

When I feed that time stamp number into an online EPOCH convertor, it comes back fine (8th april approx 13:25 GMT)

Can anyone assist? Is it something to do with the epoch being a number string as opposed to an integer?

Comment: Seems like someone already multiplied the timestamp by 1000 for you :)... try decoding `1365427203` instead.

Comment: Which means it isn't really a Unix timestamp. You should fix the API sending the JSON or tell the people running it to do so.

Comment: Of course, moment of stupidity on my part for not seeing that.. now I am just getting 'Invalid date' with the same code (minus the *1000)

Comment: ok when I put in the number in the code that mirrors the value of the timestamp, it works. When i try to use the variable as pulled from the JSON it fails... so close

Comment: yeah, just had to do a parseInt on the json. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the users who commented.

Timestamp was already being multiplied by 1000...

All I did to fix was to use the code above but without the *1000 then I wrapped it in a parseInt so the function new that the info was a number, and not a string of numbers